# Iterating using two variables

Tags: python, loops

I need to get an output like this, if possible using a single for loop.

```
0 0
0 1
1 2
1 3
2 4
2 5
3 6
3 7
```

Is there an elegant way to do this ?

For the context of my problem, I actually have two lists `A = [1,2,3]` and `B = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Note that list B is twice the length of list A. I need to create a new list by appending each element in list A with two consecutive elements in list B. So this should result in list `C = [(1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,5),(3,6)]

Comment: What have you tried already? Please show your code attempt and explain what is not working out for you, currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and `zip(A, A)` to "duplify" `A`, then `zip` with `B`:

```
>>> A = [1,2,3]
>>> B = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> zip(itertools.chain(*zip(A, A)), B)
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [(A[i//2], b) for i, b in enumerate(B)]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
zip([item for sub in [[el] * 2 for el in A] for item in sub], B)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the `zip` function to iterate two lists.

```
def merge_lists(list1, list2):
    assert(len(list2) == 2 * len(list1))
    chunks = [list2[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(list2),2)]
    for element, chunk in zip(list1, chunks):
        for element2 in chunk:
            yield(element, element2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), i.e.:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for tuple in zip([a for a in A for _ in (0,1)], B):
    print tuple[0], tuple[1]
```